# Validation HashMap->Radiobutton. Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have another problem! :)

I have a hashmap linked on jsp with a radiobutton. When I check a radio, my hashmap is populated with the param that I spec on the tag. Now I want to validate the check on radiobutton. How can I make this? Is possible with the annotations?

I have just found a solution,  using an another list. But I'm sure that exist another way, too simple and clean. With the annotations.. Exist?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the part "validate the check on radiobutton". What exactly do you want to validate? If the checked value matches one of the displayed values? Or if it **is** checked?

Comment: If it is checked. The app is a survey. I want to check if a user give an answer on the option list.

Comment: Thus, you just want to make it required?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Struts [Validation document](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html). You likely need the [Required Validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/required-validator.html) which is also available in flavor of an annotation: [`@RequiredFieldValidator`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/annotations/RequiredFieldValidator.html).